# python upload - where are tmp/FILES?

Tags: python, upload, cgi, mosso

I'm running python 2.4 from cgi and I'm trying to upload to a cloud service using a python api.  In php, the $_FILE array contains a "tmp" element which is where the file lives until you place it where you want it.  What's the equivalent in python?

if I do this

```
fileitem = form['file']
```

`fileitem.filename` is the name of the file

if i print fileitem, the array simply contains the file name and what looks to be the file itself.

I am trying to stream things and it requires the tmp location when using the php api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is a real file, but the `cgi.FieldStorage` unlinked it as soon as it was created so that it would exist only as long as you keep it open, and no longer has a real path on the file system.

You can, however, change this...

You can extend the `cgi.FieldStorage` and replace the `make_file` method to place the file wherever you want:

```
import os
import cgi

class MyFieldStorage(cgi.FieldStorage):
    def make_file(self, binary=None):
        return open(os.path.join('/tmp', self.filename), 'wb')
```

You must also keep in mind that the `FieldStorage` object only creates a real file if it recieves more than 1000B (otherwise it is a `cStringIO.StringIO`)

**EDIT**: The `cgi` module actually makes the file with the `tempfile` module, so check that out if you want lots of gooey details.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking to change the way it deals with files, but when I try to write the contents of file in chunks it works fine for small text files, but any video or images are uploaded corrupt.  I thought this might be solved by streaming it as the php api does

Comment: If you want to stream it, you can return an object with a write function to take the data from the Field Storage as it receives it. This is what I am doing to get AJAX upload progress info back to the browser for one of my projects.

Comment: i'm trying to get files onto a cdn cloud container, so "stream" has to happen according to their api.  I like your suggestion to override FieldStorage, but it's not working for me right now.  I'm sort of new to python and might be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet taken from my site:

```
h = open("user_uploaded_file", "wb")
while 1:
    data = form["file"].file.read(4096)
    if not data:
        break
    h.write(data)
h.close()
```

Hope this helps.